# Having trouble with onMouseEnter event in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onmouseover

I'm trying to build a navbar, using React and hooks, where each div will change to a specific color on an onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave. I can't figure out why they're all affected if i hover over one. I guess I'm asking how I could make them independent of one another.

Sorry if this is a really obvious mistake. Still really green. Thanks again!

Here is a link to the CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-snowflake-twojb?file=/src/navbar.js

Comment: Why do you want to do it in javascript? CSS can do that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code.
You can check it in https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-lake-u3oox?file=/src/navbar.js

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function `setBackground` to set the background color in the `hoverStyle` CSS class which affects to all `<div className="hoverStyle">` tags.

There are many options to do that. If you want to do it with React, one way of do it is creating a CSS class like this:

```css
.active {
   background-color: #ffac4e;
}
```

then, create a functional component

```js
const Activable = ({ className, children, bgColor}) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('#fff');

  return (
    <div className={`${ className } ${ active }`
      onMouseEnter = {() => setActive( bgColor )}
      onMouseLeave = {() => setActive('#fff')}
    >
      { children }
    </div>
  )
}
```

then replace your ` with this new component like this:

```js
<Activable className="hoverStyle" bgColor="#ffac4e">
   <div style = {navChildLeft}>2020</div>
     <div style = {navChildTop}>
        Shy RL <br />
     Digital - Album art
   </div>
</Activable>
```

and repeat with the rest of `<div>`'s

Answer (score 0):

With react, it is important to think about reusable components. How can you create something that you can reuse over and over again in different parts of your project.

Take a look at this sample of your project broken into components. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-brook-3jror?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I would recommend reading this to help out: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html